# frame setVisible(false) and dispose() can not kill the process

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have following scenario (2 classes)

Frame1(next button)
Frame2(prev button, close button)
Frame1 opened (instance 1)
to go Frame1 - Frame2 (`frame1.setVisible(false)` and `frame2.setVisible(true)`) (instance 2)
to go Frame2 - Frame1 (`frame2.setVisible(false)` and `frame1.setVisible(true)`) (instance 3)
again Frame1 - Frame2 (`frame1.setVisible(false)` and `frame2.setVisible(true)`) (instance 4)

in above process  4 instances (If program opened then noted as instance)
now during close from Frame2, I m using `frame1.dispose()` and `frame2.dispose()`
here only 2 times instances are disposed.
But the problem is:  still 2 instances are not disposed.
But only only one process is an alive. How is it possible?
In above scenario should I dispose all instances to kill the process ?

Comment: what do you mean by "instances"? how'd you know "still 2 instances are not disposed"? If possible improve the question as it is still hard to follow.

Comment: If the program opened then noted as instance. neway I have edited thank you!!!

Comment: Hmm. Just tried and it really didn't work! Interesting. It'd be interesting to investigate this but if you're going with this implementation then you're probably going to end up in more trouble. Take some of the suggestions e.g. using `CardLayout` or a `JDialog` instead of `JFrame`. Seriously, avoid multiple JFrames.

Answer (score 1):

You consider to do like this if you do not want to go with `CardLayout`

Create a constructor in `Frame1` with argument of `Frame2` as shown below and store frame2 object locally.

```
public class Frame1{
    private Frame2 frame2Obj;
    public Frame1(Frame2 frame1Obj){
        this.frame2Obj = frame2Obj;
    }
    private openFrame1(){
         frame2Obj.setVisible(true);
         this.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Similarly create a constructor in `Frame2` with argument of `Frame1` as shown below and store frame1 object locally.

```
public class Frame2{
    private Frame1 frame1Obj;
    public Frame2(Frame1 frame1Obj){
        this.frame1Obj = frame1Obj;
    }
    private openFrame1(){
         frame1Obj.setVisible(true);
         this.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Now you will have only two instances.

Comment: not my that problem... System.exit(0) terminate the whole system

Answer (score 1):

- default value [`DefaultCloseOperation` for `JFrame` is `HIDE_ON_CLOSE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html#windowevents)
- have to set `DefautlCloseOperation` for `JFrame` with proper value `(EXIT_ON_CLOSE)`
- don't create an second or more [`JFrames`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html), use [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) instead
- use [`JDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) instead another [`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html), in the case that there are real reasons

Comment: yea your idea is welcome... thank you..but the development is finished and I need to kill the process properly of multiple instance....